# Swagger codegen generate too long string literals

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-codegen

I need to generate classes based on provided swagger file. Unfortunately I have no influence on content of this file.

My config in gladle looks like:

```
task generateApi {
doLast {
    def config = new CodegenConfigurator()
    config.setInputSpec("file:///$projectDir/$swaggerSourceFile")
    config.setOutputDir("$projectDir/$swaggerTargetFolder")
    config.setLang('spring')
    config.setAdditionalProperties([
            'interfaceOnly'       : true,
            'apiPackage'          : 'somepackage',
            'modelPackage'        : 'somepackage.domain',
            'sourceFolder'        : '',
            'java8'               : true,
            'dateLibrary'         : 'java8',
            'skipDefaultInterface': true
    ])
    new DefaultGenerator().opts(config.toClientOptInput()).generate()
}
}
```

Exception which I`m getting is : "error: constant string too long"

Problem is that even I set 'skipDefaultInterface', swagger will generates it. In default interface it generates default response entity body which is json file which is 70k char long string.

Please help!

Comment: Can you also post the API definition from which you generate the code? Or a minimal API definition that can be used to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Unfortunately I don`t know If I will not share any company secret - even If file is widely available :/

Comment: How about a minimal example with no private details? Or can you reproduce the issue with some other public API definition, e.g. those from https://apis.guru/browse-apis/? Without seeing an API spec it's impossible to troubleshoot.

Comment: @Helen Anonymization is not possible - too many fields inside, and guru apis all works.

Problem is that return value is really complicated :/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is a known issue with the `spring` generator in Swagger Codegen:
https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/9055

A PR for this issue is available but not yet merged (as of February 2020):
https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/pull/8691

Try using [openapi-generator](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator) v. 4.2.2 or later which is supposed to include a [similar fix](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/pull/2903).