# Export of spring stub from swagger hub results with compilation error

Tags: java, spring, swagger, swagger-codegen

I have a swagger YML definition as:

```
/path/getABC:
    get:
      tags:
      - Tag-ABC
      summary: Fetch all ABC
      description: This API used to get all ABC list.
      operationId: fetchABC
      responses:
        "200":
          description: 'This api return ABC list for external and internal ABC'
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/ApiResponseABC'
              examples:
                success:
                  value: '{"data":[ {"id":10,"abcId":"ABC",...},
                    {"id":12,"abcId":"CDE",...},
                     ....
                     ....
                    {"id":2,"abcId":"XYZ",...], #<<--too long text-->>>
                    "status":"SUCCESS", "statusCode":200, "message":"ABC Completed"}'
                error-404:
                  value: '{ "statusCode":404, "status":"FAILED", "message":"Unable
                    to fetch ABC list." }'
                error-500:
                  value: '{ "statusCode":500, "status":"FAILED", "message":"We are
                    unable to process your request, please try again." }'
```

And when I export server stub as with default spring setting and then build the code which is showing compilation error with message `Error:(79,88) java: constant string too long`

```
public ResponseEntity<ApiResponseABC> fetchABC() {
        String accept = request.getHeader("Accept");
        if (accept != null && accept.contains("application/json")) {
            try {
                return new ResponseEntity<ApiResponseABC>(objectMapper.readValue(" too long string as example shown in swagger api", ApiResponseABC.class), HttpStatus.NOT_IMPLEMENTED);//String is too long and can not compile showing too Error:(79,88) java: constant string too long
            } catch (IOException e) {
                log.error("Couldn't serialize response for content type application/json", e);
                return new ResponseEntity<ApiResponseCpo>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
            }
        }

        return new ResponseEntity<ApiResponseABC>(HttpStatus.NOT_IMPLEMENTED);
    }
```

The string is of `79975` characters long. So, why is this happening? Although there are multiple solutions for manual interpretation, I don't want any manual modification of code. So, please suggest a better approach.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swagger codegen generate too long string literals](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60281401/113116)

Comment: @Helen Thanks. I also think it's an open issue.